# Presto Trino Sql , select Date which is two days before

Tags: sql, presto, trino

```
select  current_date as current_dated from table
```

select  current_date - interval(2,days) as current_dated , is what I am looking for

Comment: `current_date - interval '2' day`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options, for similar syntax you can use [`interval '2' day`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html), another option is [`date_add`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_add):

```sql
select current_date - interval '2' day
    , date_add('day', -2, current_date)
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-02 | 2022-06-02 |